# Inverted Doodle

Tags: survey

I'm looking for something like doodle but I want the participants to submit where they are not free. So I can find dates based on this.
I think it could be easier to do this way around.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but maybe it'll help someone.

You can do this with https://pollunit.com

In the "Advanced schema settings" you can select "Lowest resistance" as target. This allows your participants to cast negative votes. This works for dates, free text, images etc.

I am one of the developers.